# archive files in all dates (previous and current day ) with talend

Tags: java, talend

I created a job which archive files in current day. I need now to improve my job to archive files in all days (current and previous days).
I used a global variable like :

```
"*_"+ TalendDate.formatDate("yyyy_MM_dd",TalendDate.getCurrentDate())+".csv"
```

[this job get files from FTP and archive them in current day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czviM.png)

How can I change the global variable to archive in all days?

I have used `Tloop` but no result.

Comment: Do you need one archive file for each date , or one archive file containing all csv files at execution time ?

Comment: thanks for reply , i need one archive file for each date. i can now archive the files in current day , so i need to archive the files in previous days also

Answer (score 0):

I think you could achieve this with a double reading of your input folder, with a tIterateToFlow component.

[image]

- In the tFileList_1 , get all the csv, without a mask (or just *.csv)
- in tIterateToFlow, extract the date in the input Filename (given your example , this should do the trick : `StringHandling.RIGHT(((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILE")),14)`
- Add a tFlowTo Iterate, no customization needed
- In tFileList_2 , you can then filter on the field created in tIterateToFlow : this is your pattern : `"*_"+((String)globalMap.get("row2.dateFile"))`
- tFileArchive_1  can then zip file in an outputfolder (with the same filemask as in your tFileList)

I tested it quickly, it seems to work. Didn't check with tFTP components tho.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I am really thankful for the above solution. My scenario is similar but few changes.

I need to delete All files for a month & keep only files for recent 5 days & delete previous files.
I got solution from above scenario.

For above scenario one point i need to add:

```
In tfilelist2  File path (Directory) use global variable of tfilelist1 > ((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILEDIRECTORY"))
```

so you can grab current file running as per above job.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34583893)